How does PooledConnectionLifetime control pooled TCP connections in transport layer?
we know that we can use PooledConnectionLifetime and PooledConnectionIdleTimeout to pool TCP connections
e.g https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-connection-pooling-in-dotnet-core
var socketsHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
{
     PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
     PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
     MaxConnectionsPerServer = 2
};

var client = new HttpClient(socketsHandler);

var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 200).Select(i => client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com"));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

this has benefits to prevent socket exhaustion (https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and DNS issue (https://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html)
But how does PooledConnectionLifetime and PooledConnectionIdleTimeout control pooled TCP connections in transport layer?
My assumptions are:
a. these two settings PooledConnectionLifetime and PooledConnectionIdleTimeout will be used to create a TCP connection with Keep-Alive, so the TCP connection can stay active and therefore can be reused for same requests (identified by same destination ip address and same port number)
b. so those two settings are being used, the tcp connection for client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com") won't send a FIN package to the google server, because the TCP connection cannot be reused after client sends a FIN to indicate it want to terminate the connection,
Are my assumptions correct? if it is, where is the source code that set Keep-Alive setting? I track it down to HttpConnectionPool(https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/ConnectionPool/HttpConnectionPool.cs)
still haven't found how the Keep-Alive being sent. There must be somewhere that managed code transit to C++ code that sets Keep-Alive and then create a TCP connection with keep-alive in the kernel, where is it?

Keep-Alive has been deprecated since HTTP/2. Hence I imagine the implementation would rely on other means to keep the connection alive? Maybe it sends dummy messages periodically?

You could clone the source and search the usages of PooledConnectionLifetime and PooledConnectionIdleTimeout with Visual Studio.
